# Django Admin - Any replacement css built by the community

Tags: django, django-admin

Looking to update the look and feel of my django admin interface, purely for aesthetic reasons.

Does anyone know of any available prepackaged css/javascript to replace the default admin UI?

Comment: Grapelli is probably the most popular admin-customizing package. Look here: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/admin-interface/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Grappelli](http://www.grappelliproject.com/) yet?